# Await Inside Foreach Keyword

Tags: c#, .net, foreach

I have a `List` of `Task<bool>` that i want to iterate it and depending on the awaited result i decide whether to continue or break but ironically the `foreach` just executes the tasks and await keyword does not work

Here is my code

```
private async void Execute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tList = new List<Task<bool>> { Method1(), Method2()};

    foreach (var task in tList)
    {
        var result = await task;

        if(!result)
            break;
    }
}

public async Task<bool> Method1()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Method1");
    return false;
}

public async Task<bool> Method2()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Method2");
    return true;
}
```

***Result : Both functions are execute.***

Question : How could i use await inside `foreach` ?.

And **thanks** in advance.

Comment: `Method1()` returns `true`, so I would expect your loop to continue. That said, you have a fundamental issue here: you're kicking off both tasks prior to starting the loop, so even if the first task returned `false`, it's possible that the second task has already completed. You'll still ignore any further *results*, but you won't have necessarily skipped the computation of those results.

Comment: sorry **edited it** with the same result, and it should break if false returned.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `await` within a foreach exactly as you are doing now.

> Result : Both functions are execute.

Both functions *should* execute.  The `result` isn't set to false until `Method2` returns, at which point both have already run.  You're also starting both `Task<bool>` instances before you `await` either, so both are (potentially) running before your foreach loop.

Reverse the order of your methods, and they won't both *necessarily* run (though they may, as you're starting them):

```
var tList = new List<Task<bool>> { Method2(), Method1()};
```

If you want to delay this completely, you could write it as:

```
var tList = new List<Func<Task<bool>>> { Method2, Method1};

foreach (var taskFunc in tList)
{
    var result = await taskFunc();

    if(!result)
        break;
}
```

Comment: As I mention in my comment on the question, just because you don't `await` a particular task doesn't mean it won't *run*. The issue is that the methods are both run prior to the loop, so whether awaited or not, they will both finish at some point (since there's clearly no cancellation occuring.)

Comment: see the post edit with the same Result. what i want happen is if the first method returned false don't execute the second one...

Comment: @RuneS See my edit - the second will cause this to behave as you want, as I don't start the task until you're in the loop...